# I am facing trouble while installing pyopus

Tags: python, pvm

I am using ubuntu 10.04 in virtualbox and my host os is windows 8.1. I was trying to install pyopus from its source by using the instructions given here: http://fides.fe.uni-lj.si/pyopus/installation.html

I have installed all the prerequisites successfully for installing pyopus.

While building pyopus from the given setup.py, this is where I was stopped  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwbq_C5RvgSqNGVtOHhJSUdhZWc/edit?usp=sharing.

What should I do to install pyopus successfully? Please suggest.